# Need help with: given $\forall x.\forall y.p(x,y)$, use the Fitch System to prove $\forall x.\forall y.p(y,x)$.

Tags: logic

as per the title I need help with this question:

> Given $\forall x.\forall y.p(x,y)$, use the Fitch System to prove $\forall x.\forall y.p(y,x)$.

I have got to the point where I have used universal elimination to get $p(a,b)$ with $a$ and $b$ being my dummy variables but I do not know how to use universal introduction to introduce the $x$ and $y$ back in.

Using this Fitch system
http://intrologic.stanford.edu/coursera/exercise.php?exercise=exercise_08_05

Comment: Use Universal Introduction to get $\forall y p(y,b)$ from $p(a,b)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Unfortunately, Stanford's implementation of Fitch does not allow that to be done in one step.  You have to finesse their system a bit.

Comment: @GrahamKemp - Not clear... You cannot use $\forall$-Intro in that system ? It's funny...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, you can use it, but Universal Introduction is implemented on the [Stanford Fitch system](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) by checking a line and inputting which of its variables are to be bound to the quantifier -- it does not substitute anything. You have to go from $\rm p(X)$ to $\rm AX:p(X)$. You cannot go *directly* to $\rm AY:p(Y)$.  It is annoying.

Comment: @MM360  How are you going?

Answer (score 1):

The trick with Stanford's implementation is that *universal elimination* substitutes the bound variable for the input, while *universal introduction* just binds the input variable.  So you have to go through a little rigmarole involving a third variable to swap.

Here's the last few lines to give you the idea.

$$\rm{AX:AY:p(X,Y)\\\vdots\\AX:p(Z,X)\hspace{10ex}\textit{Try to get here}\\AZ:AX:p(Z,X)\hspace{5ex}\textsf{Universal Introduction (input Z)}\\AX:p(Y,X)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Universal Elimination (input Y)}\\AY:AX:p(Y,X)\hspace{4.5ex}\textsf{Universal Introduction (input Y)}}$$

Comment: Thanks @Graham Kemp. That pointed me in the right direction. :)